# Why are the Vue props wrapped in `Partial<>`?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, volar

I'm using a stack of technologies, so I'm finding it hard to find the source of the problem.

Here is the Stack:

- Vue 3
- TypeScript
- Vite
- VSCode / Volar
- unplugin-vue-macros (https://github.com/sxzz/vue-macros)
- unplugin-vue-components (https://github.com/antfu/unplugin-vue-components)

I have a component (`MetadataTemplate.vue`) which exports these props:

```
interface Props {
  link: Link
  type: 'link' | 'collection'
  showSuccess?: Function
  refresh?: Function
  displayButtons?: boolean
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  type: 'link',
  refresh: () => {}
})
```

Notice that `type` is a required property. However, this code throws a TypeScript error:

```
<MetadataTemplate
  :type="pageType"
  :link="link"
/>
```

`pageType` is of type `'link' | 'collection'`. *However*, TypeScript (Volar) reports:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"collection" | "link" | undefined'.ts(2322)

MetadataTemplate.vue(33, 3): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'Partial<{ type: "collection" | "link"; refresh: Function; }> & Omit<Readonly<ExtractPropTypes<__VLS_WithDefaults<__VLS_TypePropsToRuntimeProps<Props>, { ...; }>>> & VNodeProps & AllowedComponentProps & ComponentCustomProps, DefaultKeys<...>> & Record<...>'
```

In other words, it's exporting the props as a Partial. Is this something that Vue / TypeScript always does? Or something that Volar expects? I don't know what could be translating a set of props to Partial props.

Comment: Well yes, but that isn't the cause for the error.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I figured it out.

As @zenly said, the Partial wasn't the cause of the error. The error was that Volar / TypeScript was inferring the type of `pageType` within VSCode as `'link' | 'collection'` but it wasn't *actually* of that type, because Vue's language services weren't correctly inferring the type of `pageType` by the time it was bound to the template (and was inferring that it was just a string).

I fixed it by explicitly defining `pageType` as that type.